# How to get child product image in Magento Cart

Tags: configurable-product, image, shopping-cart

I am trying to get the child product image of a configurable product that was added to cart by the customer.

For example, if the customer added a pair of red shoes to the cart I would like to show that color in the shopping cart.

I have set "Show product Thumbnail Itself"

The problem is this function from a colour swatch extension

```
public function findColorImage($value, $arr, $key, $type)
{
    $found = '';
    if(isset($arr[$key])) {
        $total = count($arr[$key]);
        if($total>0)
        {
            for($i=0; $i<$total;$i++)
            {
                if($value == ucwords($arr[$key][$i]))//if it matches the color listed in the attribute
                {
                    $found = $arr[$type][$i];//return the image src
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if ($found == '') {
        if (isset($arr['image'])){
            $found = $arr['image'][0];
        }
    }
    return $found;
}
```

in the template `colorselectorplus/cart/item/default.phtml`

findColorImage($_item->getProductId(),$product_base,'color', 'image'); ?>

Which is being called from Helper/Data.php for some reason it only returns the Base image for the product and ignores the correct image for the colour.

I've tried changing `image` to use `thumbnail` but I'm not having any joy...

Has any other developer come across this issue with this extension and managed to fix it?

I'd don't mind even a hot fix right now...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Goto `admin>System>Configuration>Checkout>Shopping Cart>Configurable Product Image` make it `Product Thumbnail Itself` this make child product image
Instead of sending

```
$_item->getProductId()
send $_item
and put somelogic
$_item
```

for configurable product $_Item>getSku give child product a other time give main products.
so just child product using item sku

**I guess you have used third party extension so i have change some change according my concept**
change

**Step1**:instead `of send product send all item object`

```
findColorImage($_item->getProductId(),$product_base,'color', 'image');
```

to

```
findColorImage($_item,$product_base,'color', 'image');
```

**Step2**: some change on  function

```
public function findColorImage($item, $arr, $key, $type)
{
    /* $value  set here*/
    $value=$item->getProductId();

    $found = '';
    if(isset($arr[$key])) {
        $total = count($arr[$key]);
        if($total>0)
        {
            for($i=0; $i<$total;$i++)
            {
                if($value == ucwords($arr[$key][$i]))//if it matches the color listed in the attribute
                {
                    $found = $arr[$type][$i];//return the image src
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if ($found == '') {
        if (isset($arr['image'])){
            $found = $arr['image'][0];
        }
    }
    /*  for configurable product send child product image */
    if($item->getProductTypeId="configurable"){
        $ChildProduct=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$item->getSku());
        $found=Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($ChildProduct, 'thumbnail');

    }
    return $found;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you comments. I have mentioned in this post that I have already that to yes...

Comment: apologies but its not quite clear what you mean???